# Fit node to another node in a separate scope that has been shifted and canvas transformed

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, nodes, coordinates

I want to fit a node to another node which is defined in a different scope which has been subject to the options "(x)shift and transform canvas" (see example code and image). Without any canvas or shift operations, the fit works as expected. With the transform canvas option, however, the fit does not work. How can I get the "world coordinates", i.e. the coordinates after all scope modifications have been applied, of a node?

### Code:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\usepackage[paperwidth=8cm,paperheight=12cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\section*{Without Canvas Transform}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}
        \node[ultra thick, draw, blue, minimum width=2cm, circle, xshift=15] (n1) {};
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}
        \node[thick, fill opacity=0.3, fill=yellow, draw, inner sep=0, yellow, fit=(n1)] (n2) {};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\section*{With Canvas Transform}
\vspace{10pt}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[transform canvas={scale=1.5}, xshift=15]
        \node[ultra thick, draw, blue, minimum width=2cm, circle] (n1) {};
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}
        \node[thick, fill opacity=0.3, fill=yellow, draw, inner sep=0, yellow, fit=(n1)] (n2) {};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Fit nodes with and without canvas transformation]

Comment: Why do you use `transform canvas` instead of `transform shape` on the node?

Comment: Please elaborate in more detail. If i use `transform shape={scale=1.5}` on either the node or the scope, the size of the node is not affected at all.

Comment: I got it now: Leave out transform canvas in the scope, just specify scale=<desired ratio> for the scope and for each node within that scope that should be scale, add transform shape.
If you write the answer (just c&p my code with the appropriate changes), I'll mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: Ah great. Sorry, I was distracted :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Transform canvas is a hardcore transformation that doesn't respect any bounding box computation or similar well-behaved updates. Hence it transforms like a boss. Here, we came to the conclusion in the comments that you would like the nodes to respect the inner transformation within the scope. That is done by the `transform shape` i.e. the shape of the node is transformed too.

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[scale=1.5,xshift=15]
        \node[ultra thick, draw, blue, minimum width=2cm, circle,transform shape] (n1) {};
    \end{scope}
    \node[thick, fill opacity=0.3, fill=yellow, draw, inner sep=0, yellow, fit=(n1)] (n2) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @HarishKumar No it's [my grandfather's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aleksandr_Lyapunov) (scientifically speaking)

Comment: Percusse, you are naughty. I was surprised at first (to see the beard.) :)